# Remove comma seprated values in postgresql

Tags: postgresql

one table alphabet has column values nvarchar and values are (A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H)
we have another table that is linked with the previous one and this table has one column
which has values (C, H).

so These two values will be deleted from the previous table columns.

| ID | values |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H,I,J,K,L,M |
| 2 | A,C,F,G,H,J,U,V,W,X,Y,Z |

second table.

| ID | values |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | C,F |
| 1 | A,Z |

FINAL OUTPUT .
TABLE A.

| ID | values |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | B,D,E,G,H,I,J,K,L,M |
| 2 | A,C,F,G,H,J,U,V,W,X,Y,Z |

Comment: Try to fix your datamodel as soon as possible. Even an array is better... You can use the functions regexp_split_to_array() or string_to_array() to split the content.

Answer (score 0):

Sample Query:

```
select 
    t1.id, 
    string_agg(t1.val1, ',') as "values"
from 
    (select "id", unnest(('{' || "values"  || '}')::text[]) as val1 from table1 
    ) as t1 
left join
    (select "id", unnest(('{' || "values"  || '}')::text[]) val2 from table2  
    ) t2 on t1.id = t2.id and t1.val1 = t2.val2 
where t2.id is null 
group by t1.id 

-- Return: 

id      values
---------------------------------
1       B,D,E,G,H,I,J,K,L,M
2       A,C,F,G,H,X,J,U,V,W,Y,Z
```